# Design window just one preview window

Tags: android

My Design window

[image]

For anyone that doesn't know my Problem yet:
Why is the left window that is usually there invisible?

Comment: change api level and refresh

Answer (score 0):

Check your gradle file like this way..
and your android studio latest then check app level gradle file..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.adruser.rafdemo"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
/*dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}*/
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


}
  repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 }
```

after add some view controls into your xml file tab to text .